# Non-archaic dumping of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, dump

I usually use `var_dump()` to dump the contents of my array so as to assess the structure. However, this becomes tedious as with larger dumps, information spreads all across my 23" screen making it extremely hard to easily pick out which key matches which value.

Is there anyway to have the contents of an array dumped vertically, similar to the fashion which the PHP Manual uses:

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
```

I'd really like to know, as this would be a great timesaver.

Any comments/suggestions/answers will be greatly appreciated ;)!!

Comment: `var_dump()/print_r()` already do this. You may just neeed to wrap their output in `<pre>` tags, or make the page's type text/plain.

Comment: Yes, this is the way `var_dump()` works. Whats the problem? Are you trying to dump to a browser? Have a look at the pages source code.

Comment: @Pixel: s'ok. you can give it to hytest below. He was the quickest for the 'real' answers.

Comment: 23"? Now that's gangsta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a non archaic debugging, var_dump, echo and other inline display of data are not the best way to go, [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and an IDE that supports debugging (netbeans, eclipse, aptana, ...) is.

However, you can improve the readability of var_dump a lot by echoing a [pre](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag before it:

```
function dump($var)
{
   echo '<pre>';
   var_dump($var);
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

(note that you can get the same sort of results by showing the source of the page instead of the html rendering)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use a custom debug() function and `<pre>`:

```
function debug($val) {
    if (defined('DEBUG') && DEBUG) { // So debugging won't show on live.
        // Turn off debugs via debug=0 in url.
        if(!@$_REQUEST['debug'] && @$_REQUEST['debug'] !== 0){ // Can see a clean page by again by just appending a url parameter.
            $vals = func_get_args();
            foreach($vals as $val){
                    echo "<pre class='debug' style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.1em;background-color:white;color:black;position:relative;z-index:10;clear:both;max-width:980px;overflow:auto'>";
                var_dump($val);
                echo "</pre>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might also want to check into http://xdebug.org/ Xdebug, which formats var_dumps for html viewing.  I've used that in the past as well.

Answer (score 0):

"view source" in your browser
or

```
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($var); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that PHP formats the array using newline characters, not 'br' elements. And because the default `Content-type` is `text/html`, the browser ignores newline characters, you don't see them.

There are two solutions:

1. View the page source
2. Set the content type to `text/plain`:

   ```
   header('Content-type: text/plain');
   var_dump($some_array);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($myValue, true).'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) can be installed and will send debug info to firebug in your browser like so: `FB::log('Log message');`

Answer (score 0):

Xdebug can replace the plain text output of var_dump() with nicely formatted/colorized HTML. See [`http://xdebug.org/docs/display`](http://xdebug.org/docs/display)